# Вопрос незнайки о CSS

Tags: css

Недавно нашел вот такую тему:

```
<div style="
   display:block;
   width: 126px; 
   height: 180px;
   background-color: red;
   border-radius:        34%   100%  19%  50%  / 100%   17%   60%  100%;">
```

Но не могу понять последнюю строчку: как можно так вот-так делать делать вообще?

Answer (score 3):

Все просто. В общем первые значения то есть : (34% 100% 19% 50%) они задают радиус по горизонтали, а вторые (100% 17% 60% 100%) задают значение по вертикали. Получается эллипс. Подробнее [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius)